# How to Efficiently List Matching Contents and File Names in Heavily Excluded Subset of Matches?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, find

This one is deceptively simple, and I imagine I'm missing something obvious... but I've been unable to find an efficient way to generate a list of:

1. File name
2. Content matching a pattern

...in the case where I *eliminate the majority of matches via single-line exclusion subpatterns* (the catch).

Out of roughly `~1,300` code files of interest, `~1,000` contain `{brandedTerm}`, based on inspection by:

Number of code files of interest that might match (based on extension):
`( printf "%s\n" $( find . -type f -name "*.{extension}" )  )| wc -l`

Number of code files... containing term:
`( printf "%s\n" $( find . -type f -name "*.{extension}" -exec grep -l "{brandedTerm}" {} \; )  )| wc -l`

The problem is that most of these matches are subpatterns I don't care about as they're comments or enumerated names or such.  What I'm trying to hunt down is usage of `{brandedTerm}` in strings, to modify/obfuscate THOSE handful of use cases for a study.

I can achieve almost what I want w/:
`find . -type f -name "*.{extension}" -exec grep "{brandedTerm}" {} \; | sed -e '/{exclusion_pattern_1}/d; ... /{exclusion_pattern_k}/d'`

...where `{exclusion_pattern_1}`, ... , `{exclusion_pattern_k}` represent the patterns matching the submatches that I don't care about (the majority of matches).

That prints the matches themselves (`2.`) post-exclusion.  The only problem is that doesn't list the files that those post-exclusion matches are found in (`1.`); a necessity given my desire to edit those matches.

Most avenues I've fiddled with (looping over matching files & concatenating the filename/match THEN excluding ***OR*** re-searching on match patterns w/ exclusions applied) have proven onerous and slow.

I'm thinking there's some easier way to find the files & print their matching content w/ exclusions, in the case where:

1. Exclusions represent the majority of matches
2. Numerous exclusion patterns apply.

Thoughts?

(Also, if there's a duplicate please let me know... was unable to find anything in this specific context, but `awk`/`sed` are well-tread, so I'm wary I didn't hit the right search phrase to find some pre-existing answer that's out there.)

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: If a file contains both excluded and non-excluded matches, should that file be listed?

Comment: *Exclusions represent the majority of matches* - how exactly? Let's say we have 10 exclusive subpatterns: some file is matched by 5 subpatterns, other - by 3 subpatterns, another one - by 7 subpatterns. So, which one should be listed?

Comment: @John1024 Unfortunately I'm on `git-bash` running on `Windows 7` for now until I resolve my firewall issues w/ Cygwin mirrors.  Hence my choice of tools is somewhat limited, although the current environment provides `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `find`, and BASH scripting.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes if containing excluded and non-excluded matches, the file name would be listed, but I would only want the non-excluded matches printed for review (after the file name).  I made add further exclusion patterns matching certain other content patterns that don't match my desired content, but which frequently are found using `{brandedTerm}`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Files shall only be printed if they have matches NOT excluded by the exclusion patterns.  In files containing a mixture of excluded and non-excluded matches (a minority of files), only the non-excluded matches shall be printed along w/ the file name.  See my `find ... | sed -e ...` attempt. That just wasn't able to print the file name w/ the non-excluded content.  In your example it's quite possible neither file would print, as you did not clarify whether any matches were NOT matched by the exclusions, the deciding factor.  Most files don't have non-excluded matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk, this will find all files in the current directory with extension `ext` that contain the regex `brandedTerm` but not either `exclude1` or `exclude2`:

```
awk '/brandedTerm/{f=1} /exclude1/ || /exclude2/{g=1; nextfile} ENDFILE{if (f && !g) print FILENAME; f=0;g=0}' *.ext
```

For those who prefer, the same command spread out over multiple lines looks like:

```
awk '/brandedTerm/{
        f=1
     }
     /exclude1/ || /exclude2/{
        g=1
        nextfile
     }
     ENDFILE{
        if (f && !g)
           print FILENAME
           f=0
           g=0
     }' *.ext
```

#### Searching recursively

To apply the above to all files in the current directory and recursively through its subdirectories that end with `.ext`, use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ext' -execdir awk '/brandedTerm/{f=1} /exclude1/ || /exclude2/{g=1; nextfile} ENDFILE{if (f && !g) print FILENAME; f=0;g=0}' {} +
```

#### How it works

Awk will implicitly loop line-by-line through every file in the argument list.

- `/brandedTerm/{f=1}`

  If the current line matches the regex `brandedTerm`, then set `f` to one (true).
- `/exclude1/ || /exclude2/{g=1; nextfile}`

  If the current line contains either the regex `exclude1` or `exclude2`, then set `g` to one (true) and skip the rest of the file.
- `ENDFILE{if (f && !g) print FILENAME; f=0;g=0}`

  At the end of each file, if `f` is true and `g` is not, then print the file name.  Then, set `f` and `g` both back to zero.

#### Other awk

For awks lacking the `nextfile` and `ENDFILE` features:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ext' -execdir awk '/brandedTerm/{f=1} /exclude1/ || /exclude2/{g=1; nextfile} END{if (f && !g) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

## Testing line-by-line

To show each line in a file that contains `brandedTerm` but not `exclude1` or `exclude2`, try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ext' -exec awk '/brandedTerm/ && (!/exclude1|exclude2/) {if (!f)print "File "FILENAME; f=1; print}' {} \;
```

As an example, consider these three files of interest:

```
$ cat dir/good1.ext
brandedTerm
exclude1 exclude2

$ cat dir/good2.ext
brandedTerm 1
exclude1 exclude2
brandedTerm 2
brandedTerm 3

$ cat dir/bad1.ext
brandedTerm exclude2
other line
```

If we run our command, we find:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.ext' -exec awk '/brandedTerm/ && (!/exclude1|exclude2/) {if (!f)print "File "FILENAME; f=1; print}' {} \;
File ./dir/good2.ext
brandedTerm 1
brandedTerm 2
brandedTerm 3
File ./dir/good1.ext
brandedTerm
```

Comment: Your solution is almost what I want, but it effectively suffers from the opposite problem to `find . -type f -name "*.{extension}" -exec grep "{brandedTerm}" {} \; | sed -e '/{exclusion_pattern_1}/d; ... /{exclusion_pattern_k}/d'`.  Where as my attempt prints non-excluded matches, but not file names, yours currently prints filenames, but not excluded matches.  The good news is I think I can modify it to do both via `/brandedTerm/ && !( /excludeTerm0/ || ... || /excludeTermK/ ) { print $0 }`, plus add a local 0/1 counter and print `FILENAME` additional before the first non-excluded hit.

Comment: If you can edit it to print the non-excluded matches beneath the filename per my comment above, I can mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick Could you clarify: does the exclusion take place on a line-by-line basis or on a file-by-file basis?  In other words, is it the intention that the appearance of any excluded pattern anywhere in a file mean that any `brandedTerm` in that file should be ignored?  Or, do we only ignore a `brandedTerm` if it is on the same line as an excluded pattern?

Comment: My application requires the exclusions to be applied line-by-line.  Almost all files will have exclusions... the ones I care about are the ones that have one or more non-excluded matches... my ultimate goal is to print the file name (as a header of sorts), followed by the list of non-excluded match(s) in just that file (files w/ no non-excluded matches would be ignored.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick OK.  See new section at the end of the answer for line-by-line testing.

Answer (score 0):

Our friend *find* allows chaining of multiple -exec statements.

```
find . -type f -name "*.{extension}" \
  -exec grep -q "{brandedTerm}" {} ";" \
  -exec egrep -v "excl_1|excl_2|excl_3" {} ";"
```

Note the q in the first grep, to set it quiet, and the egrep, which allows to add mulitple patterns to exclude (-v) with | (or).